# Split excel cell value into rows 87370225|61929359 like this

Tags: excel

I have a Excel file in which Delivery column has values like this 82296750|76987322|82637637. I have to make 3 row for these values how can i do this

Comment: Is this a once off exercise or are you looking for a programmatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-off exercise, use the "Text to Column" function in excel. You can find it under the 'Data' tab. Set the delimiter to '|'.
Once done, just transpose the column. *Cut->Paste Special->Transpose*

Answer (score 0):

If looking VBA; did you try the split() function?

If you had your string in A1, then

```
var1 = split(cells(1,1), "|",-1)
```

would return an array

```
var1 = ("82296750", "76987322", "82637637")
```